# PHP Count Array Quantity

Tags: php, arrays, shopping-cart

I have an array being set into $_SESSION["cart_array"] and the output is as such when items are in the cart.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [item_id] => 1 [quantity] => 6 ) [1] => Array ( [item_id] => 2 [quantity] => 1 ) )
```

I am trying to create a foreach loop to go through and count up the "quantity" values as to get a total cart item count, so far i have the below but i just cannot figure out how to get it into a string variable so i can display it on other pages.

```
    $cartCount = array();
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    $cartCount = 0;
} else {
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
        //$cartCount += $each_item['quantity']; <-- commented out as not working.
        //$cartCount[$each_item['item_id']] += $each_item['quantity']; <-- commented out as not working.
    }
    //Print array for debugging purposes
    print_r($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to work:

```
<?php

session_start();

$cartCount = 0;
if(isset($_SESSION['cart_array']) AND is_array(@$_SESSION['cart_array'])){
    foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] AS $each_item){
        $cartCount = $cartCount + $each_item['quantity'];
    }
}

echo $cartCount;

?>
```